# Выбрать самую новую запись из другой таблицы подходящую к каждому элементу первой и сделать выборку из результатов

Tags: mysql

Есть следующие таблицы:

***Issues:***

```
id |name
########
1  Name1
2  Name2
3  Name3
```

***Issue statuses***

```
id |name_id | date | status_id
###############################
1   1         ДАТА   2  
2   1         ДАТА   3
3   2         ДАТА   2
4   5         ДАТА   1
5   3         ДАТА   4
6   2         ДАТА   4
```

***Status***

```
id |name
########
1  Name1
2  Name2
3  Name3
```

Мне нужно одним запросом выбрать из первой таблиц те записи у которых самый новый статус равный нужному.

Пробую делать

```
    SELECT t.*, 
    (select `s`.`id` from `status` as `s` 
     left join `issue_status` as `is` on `is`.`status_id` = `s`.`id` 
     where `is`.`issue_id` = `t`.`id` 
     order by `date` desc limit 1) as status_id  FROM issue as t;
```

Но мне нужно потом сделать как то `where` по всем результатам, а по этому полю `status_id` что я получил не выходит дополнительно сделать выборку. Не знаю как поменять запрос для получения нужных мне результатов.

Comment: вы кажется не до конца дописали пример. у вас нет `from ... t`. А вообще вам надо завернуть свой запрос в еще один `select * from (ваш запрос) A where status_id=XXX`. Кстати зачем вам в подзапросе нужна таблица status я не понял, там одной issue_status достаточно. Я бы даже сказал что это обязательно. А то вы со своим left join получите некий статус даже если его в issue нет, причем какой именно предсказать невозможно

Comment: @Mike, Да я вот тоже думаю что с таблицей status я чтото лишнее сделал. А обернув в еще один `select` все работает теперь. Спасибо! Как то не подумал даже что еще в один можно его.